# Plot SVM in 3 dimension

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-visualization, svm

How can I plot SVM for a 3D dataset (with x,y,z coordinates)?

I am able to plot 3D data by using `scatterplot3d(data)`, but how does it work when using svm results?

Edit: copying from comment to answer. This should have been an edit by the OP:

3 set of data

```
data[1:10,1], data[1:10,2] and data[1:10,3] represent genuine data.
data[11:15,1], data[11:15,2] and data[11:15,3] represent userA data.
data[16:20,1], data[16:20,2] and data[16:20,3] represent userB data.
```

Then I do the SVM with:

```
 labels <- matrix( c(rep(1,10), rep(-1, 10)) )
 svp <- ksvm(data,labels, type="C-svc" , kernel='rbfdot', C=0.4, 
               kpar=list(sigma=0.2))
```

Then I have a data test with:

```
 dataTest[1,1], dataTest[1,2], dataTest[1,3] 
 predLabels = predict(svp,dataTest)
```

Editor's note: that last bit looks a bit strange with only 3 data points.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want, and am not very familiar with SVM.  I suspect that you could use `points3d` from the `rgl` package (which is what `scatterplot3d` is built on), using different colours for points which were classified as 0 and 1?  A small reproducible example ( http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 ) of the sort of output you want to plot would be helpful.

Comment: Not exactly 3D, but this paper discusses some classification plots. http://www.jstatsoft.org/v15/i09/paper

Answer (score 14):

For getting the decision boundary for a kernel-transformed SVM, I usually just predict a grid of new data and then fit a contour (or iso-surface in 3D) to the `decision value = 0` level. In 3D you can use the excellent `rgl` package for plotting, like Ben suggested, and the `contour3d()` function from the `misc3d` package. Here's an example:

```
library(e1071)
library(rgl)
library(misc3d)

n    = 100
nnew = 50

# Simulate some data
set.seed(12345)
group = sample(2, n, replace=T)
dat   = data.frame(group=factor(group), matrix(rnorm(n*3, rep(group, each=3)), ncol=3, byrow=T))

# Fit SVM
fit = svm(group ~ ., data=dat)

# Plot original data
plot3d(dat[,-1], col=dat$group)

# Get decision values for a new data grid
newdat.list = lapply(dat[,-1], function(x) seq(min(x), max(x), len=nnew))
newdat      = expand.grid(newdat.list)
newdat.pred = predict(fit, newdata=newdat, decision.values=T)
newdat.dv   = attr(newdat.pred, 'decision.values')
newdat.dv   = array(newdat.dv, dim=rep(nnew, 3))

# Fit/plot an isosurface to the decision boundary
contour3d(newdat.dv, level=0, x=newdat.list$X1, y=newdat.list$X2, z=newdat.list$X3, add=T)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i am beginner to R. this is what i wan do....example i hv 3 set of data , data[1:10,1],data[1:10,2] and data[1:10,3] represent genuine data. data[11:15,1],data[11:15,2] and data[11:15,3] represent userA data. data[16:20,1],data[16:20,2] and data[16:20,3] represent userB data. then i do the SVM with labels <- matrix(c(rep(1,10), rep(-1, 10))), svp <- ksvm(data,labels,type="C-svc",kernel='rbfdot',C=0.4,kpar=list(sigma=0.2))
then i hv a data test with dataTest[1,1],dataTest[1,2],dataTest[1,3]      predLabels = predict(svp,dataTest).How can i draw the isosurface between data and dataTest?

Comment: @jesslim Just follow the general schematic above and read the help files on these functions when you don't understand something. One small difference to my example above is that `ksvm()` in the `kernlab` package uses `type='decision'` to specify you want decision values, and returns them directly as a vector instead of as an attribute so you can skip the next `attr(...)` line. The isosurface comes solely from the training data, but of course you are free to add your test data to the same plot. Good luck!

Comment: By adjusting the `level` argument of `contour3d()`, it is possible to create margins. I added two more contours with alpha set to 0.1 for a nice transparent margin on each side.